# React-Native release crash because of unkown module (momentjs locale)

Tags: react-native, momentjs, locale

I'm creating an React-Native App, which is working fine on the emulator on DEBUG mode.
However, when I tried on on RELEASE mode, it crashes because of a failing module.

The ADB Logcat points to this message as a cause of the exception:

```
 ReactNativeJS: Requiring unknown module "./locale/pt-br".
```

I know it's being caused by a call to method "updateLocale" of momentJS library. This call is placed inside the "react-native-calendar-strip" component, when I need to set a different locale options.

I've tried a lot of different combinations on import statements, none of them working.

This is what I tried:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/pt-br';
```

or

```
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
```

I also tried to require the locale

```
require('moment/locale/pt-br');
```

Any other suggestion ?

Comment: You can check by going to `node_modules/moment/locale/pt-br` if that file exists there or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured out the solution:

I organized my imports like this:

```
import 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/pt-br';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

Then, on the beginning of the code, I had set the locale manually, before the react-native-calendar-strip could call the updateLocale method, like this:

```
moment().locale('pt-br');
```

To make sure everything works fine, I left the momentjs dependency on the same version as of the react-native-calendar-strip, which was

```
"moment": "^2.17.1",
```

Comment: You saved my life ;D on development its working, but in release build not ;/